# Can't Change User from Lockscreen, Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: users, 16.10, lock-screen

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10, with two users set up. If I lock the screen when I am logged in (either manually or through inactivity), there is no way for the other user to log in. The buttons in the top menu do nothing, and only my name shows on the screen.

Comment: Do you, or do you not see "Switch User" on the [lock screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html)? Smells like [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685794).

Comment: It does smell a lot like that, I agree. I do not see a switch user option.

Comment: On the lockscreen, if I click the gear, I have Switch Account, Guest Account, or Suspend. Also running 16.10 here.

Comment: If I click the gear, it highlights but nothing opens.

Comment: try this '$sudo apt-get --purge gnome-screensaver ;sudo apt-get --reinstall install -f gnome-screensaver'

Comment: the above command could also help. when you have hard time with something going wrong you can purge it to remove all remaining settings from it and reinstall it. keep that in mind for future use. but always reinstall it with all dependencies~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Seems you have Gnome's *user-switching* option disabled.

You can check this running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching`, which should return *true* if its disabled.

Maybe it has been disabled from *Unity Tweak Tool*, *dconf-editor*, or other tweaking tool. Anyway you can restore that functionality in a couple of ways *(or more)*.

#### Changing *user-switching* from terminal (`gsettings`)

- You can enable the *user-switching* option again running:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching true`
- To disable it again simply run:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching false`

#### Changing *user-switching* from *GUI* (`dconf-editor`)

If you prefer GUI tools for this kind of tasks, you can use `dconf-editor`. If you don't have it yet on your system, you can install it running `sudo apt install dconf-editor`.

- Open `dconf-editor` from Unity's dash.
- Navigate to *org.gnome.desktop.lockdown* on the left pane.
- Click the *disable-user-switching* item on the right pane.
- Change its value *(true/false)* from popup window and hit save button.

Personally, I prefer to keep it disabled *(for security reasons)* on systems without such requirements *(Examples: one user only, no need for fast user switch, etc...)*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you should first propose gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching to see if its true or false

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou you're right, thanks for that point! answer updated.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I'll award the bounty as soon  as the time expires. I'm not sure how this happened - I've been running nothing Ubuntu on multiple systems in my house since 2009 and never hit this. Worth the bounty to learn something new and keep peace in the family.

Comment: @Feasoron Glad to read it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment so I have to copy and correct the answer...

Seems you have Gnome's user-switching option disabled.

You can check this running gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching, which will return true if its disabled.

Maybe it has been disabled from Unity Tweak Tool, dconf-editor, or other tweaking tool. Anyway you can restore that functionality in a couple of ways (or more).
Changing user-switching from terminal (gsettings)

```
You can **disable** the user-switching option by running:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching true

To **enable** it again simply run:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching false
```

Comment: You can always suggest an edit: https://askubuntu.com/posts/878504/edit